# What is the full mechanism for the controlled reduction of an alkyne using LiAlH₄?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organic-reduction

[image: mechanism]

Was going through my notes and realised I didn't completely fill them in. The first few steps I think are quite self-explanatory but I'm really confused about the last step where I go from the five-membered ring to the final product by adding water.

I'd be really grateful if someone could clear this up or provide any suggestions!

Comment: Does [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87138/why-does-lialh4-reduce-the-double-bond-of-cinnamaldehyde-whereas-nabh4-does-not/87195#87195) related reduction help?