question regarding reduction by LiAlH4

i was getting 4 as the answer, 2 on the ester + 2 on the amide but that doesn't match the given answer. i thought about reduction of alkyne to alkene under this specific scenario but was able to find only evidence regarding reduction of 1 alkyne 3 ols
any help would be much appreciated!

What would be the given answer?

the given answer is 5

Consider $\ce{LiAlH4}$ not only as a reducing agent, but simultaneously as a strong Bronsted base.  Typically, deprotonations proceed fast -- not only the intended quench (i.e. step 2), but on the alcohol prior to a reduction of ester and amide.

@Buttonwood ah right thank you! it's literally the first step in the reaction i mentioned [controlled reduction of alkyne], i don't know how i missed that

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/181456/what-is-the-full-mechanism-for-the-controlled-reduction-of-an-alkyne-using-lialh
post for reference to what i mentioned

The alkyne can be reduced by LAH because the alcoholate (a Lewis acid) binds to the reducing species (a Lewis base) to fixate it right in space (build a model with a model kit to learn the (even intermediate) formation of cycles of five (and a bit more costly, thermodynamically speaking, six) non-H atoms is a frequent motif in organic chemistry).  That is, an isolated $\ce{C#C}$ with no $\alpha$ OH won't be reduced by LAH except if LAH is used with some transition metal catalysts simultaneously present. Be aware, LAH (used as sole reagent) is able reduce $\ce{C#N}$ to yield a terminal amine.

yep, thank you! btw would this mentioned reduction also work in the case of alpha NH2? or is NH2 not acidic enough to carry out the same reaction?

Well, what are the $\text{p}K_a$ (see for instance Reich collection)?  Because e.g., dialkylamines can be deprotonated by NaH, I presume LAH equally is powerful enough.  But the point is the (intermediate) binding of a Lewis base extending to a Lewis acid.  Now with this generalization in hand, O of carbonyl $\ce{C=O}$ could serve as an anchor, too.

Shouldn't the answer be 5 times 4 mol?

@Karsten no, since each mole of $\ce{LiAlH4}$ can donate 4 hydride ions.

@Dodo $\ce{}$ doh $\ce{}$

1 mol ester to alcohol: 0.5 mol LAH; 1 mol tertiary amide to tertiary amine: 0.5 mol LAH. Plus 0.25 mol LAH for each mol of alcohol "to quench away" (1 mol of a free carboxylic acid would require 0.75 mol to obtain the alcohol). Hence the total is 5 mol LAH for 4 mol starting material.

@Buttonwood alright, thank you!
