# Nitro-substitution

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, nitro-compounds, electrophilic-substitution

[image]

Here I expected (b) to happen via nucleophilic substitution, but contrary to that (a) is the one occuring. What exactly is happening here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bunch of crappy pictures. Up your game. ChemSE is, without a doubt, the best resource for all things chemistry-related. Play the game, get rewarded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reaction given in options (a) and (b) are called **formation of nitrate esters**. The following nitrate ester is called "ethyl nitrate",

[image: methyl-nitrate]

Firstly, $\ce{HNO3}$ and $\ce{H2SO4}$ reacts to form the $\ce{E+}$. As we know, the former is relatively weaker acid than the latter, therefore $\ce{HNO3}$ donates $\ce{OH-}$ and neutralisation takes place,

$$\ce{H2SO4 + HNO3 -> H2O + HSO4- + NO2+}$$

So, here electrophile is $\ce{NO2+}$, which gets attacked by lone pairs of *alcoholic oxygen* and finally gives "nitrate ester" as shown correctly in (a).
([Here is a video explanation of the mechanism](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/organic-chemistry/alcohols-ethers-epoxides-sulfides/reactions-alcohols-tutorial/v/formation-of-nitrate-esters) by Sal, KhanAcademy)

So, according to me, I guess (b) and (c) are **not** according to the reaction, hence they should be correct.

---

Further, if anyone is interested in (c), they should have a look at the answer in [Why does NaBH4 reduce double bonds conjugated to carbonyl groups, while LiAlH4 does not?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6977)